# Como poner una variable dentro de POSTFIELDS en un CURL en PHP?

Tags: php, api, variables, curl

Hola tengo un curl php que funciona correctamente si pongo un valor manual, pero si lo uso con una variable no me funciona, que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias por su ayuda

```
<?php
echo "La clave es ".$_REQUEST["clave"].""; //me da la clave correctamente
require_once '../config.php';
$clave1 = $_POST["clave"];
echo $clave1;  //me arroja correctamente el valor del form de donde viene
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
'https://api.algo.com/v1/ip_ranges/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Content-Type: application/json',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"cidrs": ["$clave1"]}');

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Aqui es donde no me funciona la variable $clave1

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"cidrs": ["$clave1"]}');
```

Pero en el echo de arriba si, y si pongo el valor manual tambien funciona bien.
Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Este era el metodo correcto, lo pongo por si alguien tenia el mismo problema, saludos!
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"cidrs": ["'.$clave1.'"]}');

Comment: Hola Axel, sería muy bueno si pudieses crear tu propia respuesta, y marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya verifique y este es el modo correcto en que la variable se envía:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"cidrs": ["'.$clave1.'"]}');`

Saludos